# How do I fix this chunk lighting glitch in Minecraft Bedrock Edition

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

In Minecraft Bedrock edition, PS4 to be exact I’ve being experiencing “lighting glitches” I’ve seen a few fixes to this but they don’t seem to work, and I don’t feel like moving my 26 block high mob farm over a few blocks so does anyone know a fix in Bedrock edition?

If you don’t know what a lighting glitch is or have never seen one, they mostly occur at night or in dark places, when there’s no light source for some reason certain blocks will kinda glow, and the game sees it as a legitimate light source so like as if a torch were there, monsters for example won’t spawn there, this happens due to the game doing something that makes it easier to read chunks, a fix has been made for this by dinnerbone I think, but it’s never been added because it caused too much lag at the time.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to remove the closest light source and replace it.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue many times, but before I answer though I am not sure if you have tried this as I don't know what patch your referring to. Anyway all you have to do is attempt to locate where ,if there was a legitimate block, would the source be. When you identify where the game thinks there is a light source block place one down. Then when you break it you should find that the light glitch is fixed.

If this does not work then there may be more than one source block or you have not identified the correct block. (you could also just spam glowstone or something until you find it.) If all mentioned attempts have failed then I have now idea how to fix it.